# Jetty + Nginx + SSL in Debian

Tags: nginx, ssl, jetty

I'm going to use SSL with my webapp. If I have nginx as proxy for Jetty, do I have to configure Jetty to use SSL or can I redirect SSL traffic from nginx to Jetty as HTTP traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can redirect all the https traffic to jetty as http.

don't forget to forward the proto used to make jetty aware of it:

```
proxy_set_header HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO $scheme;
```